# Texture unwrap for arbitral mesh

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, textures

How can one create a texture unwrap for an arbitral object? Just like [ALICE](http://alice.loria.fr/)'s [Graphite](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/software/3-platform/22-graphite.html).

My idea was to pick each mesh' triangle and put it to the one looong texture "frame" sequence. It took nearly 1.5 GB RAM and nearly 1 minute of time to make an incrrect texture and re-assign vertex UV coordinates with Irrlicht. Are there any better ideas?

Comment: What do you plan to use this unwrapping for ?

Comment: I suppose so, but is the texture, something you generate ? What is the content of the texture ? What are your constraints ?

Comment: there are no limitations (if you mean so, saying 'constraints'). the content of the texture would be determined after its creation. the aim is to create it first =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wildly vast topic, still being an [active research topic](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/mesh-parameterization.html).

I'm doing a few wilds guesses here, so :

If you have access to Direct3D, you could use D3DX to build the UV coordinates for your texture atlas : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206321(v=vs.85).aspx

If display performance is not too much a concern, you could try to use Disney's PTEX : http://www.disneyanimation.com/library/ptex/

Charles Bloom's Galaxy 3 'engine' also contains code for [LSCM](http://alice.loria.fr/index.php/publications.html?Paper=lscm@2002) UV generation that may be of interest : http://www.cbloom.com/3d/galaxy3/index.html

All in all, there are many solutions available, not so much robust source code available, you could google for 'mesh parameterization' to find various solutions.